# Change/update Firebase notification token or instance id forcefully via code?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, device-instance-id

What should I do that for changing or requesting the token in firebase?
the unique token generated by firebase on the basis of device information.

Comment: I'm sorry that you didn't like my edit to your question. However, please note that the `device-instance-id` tag is about the Windows Device Instance ID, and that it has nothing to do with the Firebase InstanceID. May I suggest you the `instanceid` tag? Please note that, as of now, there are only 2 questions that are using the `device-instance-id` tag in a wrong way, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now i got my answer after facing many troubles for generating new or change token of firebase for push notification.

1) Delete old Firebase token

```
let instance = FIRInstanceID.instanceID()
_ = FIRInstanceID.delete(instance)
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().delete { (err:Error?) in
    if err != nil{
        print(err.debugDescription);
    } else {
        print("Token Deleted");
    }
}
```

2) Request new Firebase token

```
if let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
    print("Token \(token) fetched");
} else {
    print("Unable to fetch token");
}

FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Error connecting to FCM. \(error.debugDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
    }
}
```

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4 & Firebase 4.8.2 (Follow simple two steps)**

**1) Delete old Token**

```swift
let instance = InstanceID.instanceID()
instance.deleteID { (error) in
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

**2) Request for new token**

```
if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
    print("Token : \(token)");
} else {
    print(“Error: unable to fetch token");
}

Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

*You can get updated token in MessagingDelegate method `didReceiveRegistrationToken` and in Refresh Token.*

```swift
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase Token :  \(fcmToken)")
}
```

Comment: This "messaging().connect" is needed for renewed token ?

Comment: yes because there is no way to renew the token, first we have to delete the token and after that requesting for a new token, So "messaging().connect" required. if you will find another way, suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: This "delete" is not used anymore, we have to use "shouldEstablishDirectChannel" boolean, and it is not refreshing the token, keep the same. When i resolve it, i will put here. Thanks!

Comment: for Swift 3:
        let instance = InstanceID.instanceID()
        instance.deleteID { (error) in
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }

Comment: How can this be done with regular objective C and the older firebase SDK?

Answer (score 4):

for now `InstanceID.instanceID().token()` is deprecated.

You should use this:

```
let instance = InstanceID.instanceID()
instance.deleteID { (error) in
  print(error.debugDescription)
}

instance.instanceID { (result, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
  } else {
    print("Remote instance ID token: \(String(describing: result?.token))")
  }
}
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

Then in AppDelegate:

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    //Here is your new FCM token
    print("Registered with FCM with token:", fcmToken)
}
```

Comment: in "instance.instanceID"  result?.token return old token. therefore no need to call this method.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATED FOR FIREBASE MESSAGING 7.3.0

```
class func regenerateFCM(){
    Installations.installations().delete { (err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err)
        }else{
            Installations.installations().authTokenForcingRefresh(true) { (result,err) in
                if let result = result {
                    print(result)
                   
                    Messaging.messaging().deleteToken { (err) in
                        if let err = err {
                            print(err)
                        }else{
                            print("FCM TOKEN DELETED")
                            Messaging.messaging().token { (token, err) in
                                if let token = token {
                                    print("NEW FCM TOKEN GENERATED")
                                    print(token)
                                }
                                if let err = err {
                                    print("ERROR WHILE GENERATING NEW FCM TOKEN")
                                    print(err)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }else if let err = err {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE FOR FIREBASE 8.5.0

```
Messaging.messaging().deleteToken { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error while generating new FCM Token")
            print(err)
        }else{
            Messaging.messaging().token { token, err in
                 if let token = token {
                    print("NEW FCM TOKEN GENERATED")
                    print(token)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? @Shahzaib 
I got new tokens but they don't work with FCM. Only the initial token works

Answer (score 3):

> Updated Answer for Swift 4, FireBase 4.8.2, FirebaseMessaging (2.0.8)

```
debugPrint("Existing Token :- \(Messaging.messaging().fcmToken!)")

let instance = InstanceID.instanceID()
instance.deleteID { (error) in
    print(error.debugDescription)
}

if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
    print("Token \(token) fetched");
} else {
    print("Unable to fetch token");
}
Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

> We receive this updated token in MessagingDelegate method as well as in Refresh Token

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to change or update the firebase token.

Create the following two methods

```
func registerFirebaseToken() {
    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("FIREBASE: Token \(token) fetched")
    } else {
        print("FIREBASE: Unable to fetch token");
    }

    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}

func unregisterFirebaseToken(completion: @escaping (Bool)->()) {
    // Delete the Firebase instance ID
    InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID { (error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("FIREBASE: ", error.debugDescription);
            completion(false)
        } else {
            print("FIREBASE: Token Deleted");
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Call the

> unregisterFirebaseToken(:)

and in the closure check if true then call

> registerFirebaseToken()

this will fail for the first time and one of the delegate method will be called i.e.

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        registerFirebaseToken()
    }
}
```

This time

> registerFirebaseToken()

will be called again from the delegate method and you will get a new token.

Comment: Its working at first time only, then not receive notification from firebase console and apps. Permission is allowed and token is refreshed and tried with refresh token. Any idea for push notification are not coming?