# FirebaseInstanceIdService on TokenRefresh

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented push notifications on my app a couple of months ago.  My problem is we had to change the firebase cert on AWS and now there are a lot of push notification failures.  We are due to rollout an update on Monday.

I know in the following cases:

- App deletes Instance ID
- App is restored on a new device
- User uninstalls/reinstall the app
- User clears app data

`FirebaseInstanceIdService` gets fired and in turn `onTokenRefresh()` gets called.  My question is however, if the user receives an update to their application, is that service also fired, is an update the equivalent to `app is restored on a new device`?

This will solve the push failures if so as I register the token with AWS on receipt,

Any info would be great

Comment: An update won't change your token,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onTokenRefresh not getting called in signed APK, if previous version of app installed doesn't have FCM implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633285/ontokenrefresh-not-getting-called-in-signed-apk-if-previous-version-of-app-inst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think an app update will cause Firebase to create a new token. You can use this code to force Firebase:

```
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

You can do this in your main Activity for example, and save a boolean in the shared preferences once it is done so you don't refresh the token on each launch.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is however, if the user receives an update to their application, is that service also fired, is an update the equivalent to app is restored on a new device?

Nope. App is restored on a new device means that user has upgraded to a new device.

You may want to read this thread [Change/update Firebase notification token or instance id forcefully via code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315345/change-update-firebase-notification-token-or-instance-id-forcefully-via-code) for generating new token.