# Delete FCMToken in Swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4

I am using to send notifications to my app, when my app is installed I get the fcmtoken with this line

```
Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
```

Now, I want to delete the fcmToken whe user log out but I don't understand this:

```
Messaging.messaging().deleteFCMToken(forSenderID: String, completion: MessagingDeleteFCMTokenCompletion)
```

I don't understand, What do I have to do? thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change/update Firebase notification token or instance id forcefully via code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315345/change-update-firebase-notification-token-or-instance-id-forcefully-via-code)

Comment: but there, it uses InstanceID

Comment: Above two links provided are for deprecated InstanceID. That's not what OP means.